# Running Vue devServer proxy with https backend for websocket

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, ssl, websocket, https

I have a springboot server running with https (for websocket connections), with following config:

application.properties

```
server.port: 9080
server.ssl.key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: XXXXXX
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: XXXXXX
```

and web config

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/greeting").setHandshakeHandler(new CustomHandshakeHandler())
                .setAllowedOrigins("https://192.168.0.101:9000", "chrome-extension://ggnhohnkfcpcanfekomdkjffnfcjnjam").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

The UI is a vue dev server running on port 9000, with following config:

vue.config.js

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  "devServer": {
    "port": 9000,
    "https": {
      "key": fs.readFileSync('./certs/privkey.pem'),
      "cert": fs.readFileSync('./certs/cert.pem')
    },
    "proxy": {
      "/": {
        "target": "https://192.168.0.101:9080",
        "ws": true,
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
      }
    },
    "overlay": {
      "warnings": true,
      "errors": true
    }
  },
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],
  publicPath: "./"
}
```

certs folder is at same level as src folder, and the key and certificates were generated using following steps:

1. Generate keystore:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650
```

2. Generate certificate in pem format from keystore

```
openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12  -nokeys -out cert.pem
```

3. Generate private key in pem format from keystore:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12  -nodes -nocerts -out privkey.pem
```

and in my vue file I am creating new connection using:

```
import SockJS from "sockjs-client";
import Stomp from "webstomp-client";
...
var socket = new SockJS("/greeting");
this.ws = Stomp.over(socket);
...
this.ws.send("/app/message", JSON.stringify({"id":12, "name":"dev"}), {});
```

My problem was even after adding configuration for https in both frontend and backend, I was getting net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on the UI side

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I did was, in my web-config in setAllowedOrigins() I was still using http instead of https for the url of the ui dev server.

I know this isn't a question per say, but hopefully all these steps helps somebody